# Does Aharanov's proof of the universality of CCNOT+Hadamard carry over to CSWAP+Hadamard?

Tags: universal-gates

In an old [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301040) from 2003, D. Aharanov simplified Shi's proof that CCNOT (or Toffoli) gates + Hadamard gates together form a computationally universal gate set for quantum computing. The CCNOT gate is well-known to be computationally universal for reversable *classical* computing; another similarly well-known such gate is the CSWAP (or Fredkin) gate.

*Can we plug in the Fredkin gate into Aharanov's paper to prove the universality of CSWAP + Hadamard for **quantum** computing?*

In her proof of the universality of Toffoli + Hadamard, Aharanov considers $\Lambda(U)$ as a controlled version of $U$ - she writes the Toffoli gate as $\Lambda^2[X]$.  Does something similar work for CSWAP?

Toffoli + Hadamard is an interesting computationally universal quantum gate set, at least because there's never any imaginary amplitudes (unless provided by ancilla qubits).  The Fredkin gate is an interesting computationally universal *classical* gate, because the one's count (Hamming weight) is conserved between input and output.

Comment: I believe you can apply $CSWAP$ to the same Real-Imaginary encoding Aharanov used. This should make a $\Lambda [iI]$ gate which is equivalent to $S\otimes I$ Then, since you already have $H$; you have the Clifford group. Finally, use the result that Clifford plus anything ($CSWAP$ in this case) is universal.

Comment: @JonasAnderson I'm starting to think that this is on the right track.  Can you expand it to a formal answer?

Comment: I tried sketching the idea out and now I'm not sure if it works. The $CSWAP$ doesn't implement the encoded gate I thought it did.